# Kubernetes Ingress Address not assigned anymore

Tags: kubernetes

I am very new to Kubernetes world. I have a simple Python API running on a Kubernetes Cluster (using the manifest for Deployment, Service, Ingress below). The API was running fine on the host "http://myhost". For some reason I had to delete the resources and, when I reapplied them, I noticed that no address was assigned to the Ingress anymore. I have tried to play around with the parameters in the files below but I cannot find the solution and I am quite desperate now. Find below the 3 yaml files.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: applicationname-deployment
  namespace: namespacename
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: applicationname
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: applicationname
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: applicationname
        image: mydockerimage
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: applicationname-service
  namespace: namespacename
spec:
  selector:
    app: applicationname
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  type: ClusterIP
```

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: applicationname
  namespace: namespacename
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myhost
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: applicationname-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

When running the `kubectl get ingress` command I would expect to find an address which instead is not assigned and for this reason (I assume) when I curl I get that the host cannot be resolved. Everything was working fine until few hours ago with exactly the same yaml files. Please help me!

Comment: Please mention which ingress controller you use and if you are on cloud please mention cloud provider

Comment: I am on Azure but I am using my own domain. I have not explicitly installed any ingress controller, just specified "kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx" in the annotations

Comment: But when you use "kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx" a [prerequisite](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#prerequisites) is that nginx ingress controller must be installed else "kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx" is of no use. As no controller is monitoring this ingress to create a Load Balancer.